# When mDNSResponder will generate more network traffic

Tags: macos, bonjour, network-traffic

I know mDNSResponder is a bonjour service.I need to test my application by generating more bonjour traffic.

after googling ,I have tried giving prints to bonjour printers,and shared the iTunes media and accessed in different machines.

I don't know how to conclude how much traffic that this mDNSResponder has generated.I wanted to know how to generate more bonjour traffic on mac.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dns-sd command line tool